# Is $a>b\iff \neg(b\geq a)$ true in constructive maths?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

1. Is $a>b\iff \neg(b\geq a)\;$ true in constructive maths? Why (not)?
2. Also: is $\neg(a > b) \iff b\geq a\;$ true in constructive maths? Why (not)?

Comment: In an ordered set $(X,<)$, the relation $\ge$ is usually defined to be the complementary of $<$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: What do you mean? I think that the relation $\geq$ is defined as $a\geq b\iff (a> b\lor a = b)$. What is an "ordered set"? Do you mean "partially ordered set"? And why does the definition of an "ordered set" defines $\geq$ as the complementary of $<$? If you mean "poset", then this doesn't make sense. The only axioms that define a poset are reflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity.

Comment: @ajotatxe In a totally ordered set, that's true, but not in any ordered set. We generally define $a\geq b$ is "$a=b$ or $b<a$."

Comment: But you have to say what context you are talking about - are $x,y$ real numbers, rationals, or integers? @user7280899

Comment: @user7280899 how is it that you know the definition of "partial order" but not "(total) order". Total order is one where one and precisely one of the three conditions must be true: a < b; b<a; a=b for any two elements. So in a logic that has excluded middle.  if you rule out two, you must have the third, and if you rule out one you must have one of the other two.  So if $b \not < a$ then either $a< b$ or $a =b$ (in other words $a\le b$).  If $b < a$ then neither $a < b$ or $a=b$ is possible.  So they are compliments. **IF** our logic system has excluded middle and we have an oredered set.

Comment: @fleablood But the constructive reals are not a constructive total order - there are real $x$ where we can't decide if $x<0,x>0$ or $x=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Then, I suppose, that will make the answer to this question: "No.  From a constructive point of view the reals aren't a total order."  Is that because constructivist believe defining an "exclusive or" is impossible?  Or is it because they "chose" to make the reals partial. Or did they assume the reals "existed" first and we can't prove it is total?  Or did they construct "their" reals (as opposed to "the other" reals) to not be total ordered?

Comment: There are many "constructive maths". The make the question precise, you need to specify which one you mean.

Comment: @CarlMummert  ping me when you (hopefully) answer (ping me here, or below your (hopeful) answer).  :-)

Comment: @amWhy: I finally finished writing an answer. I hope it is clear, as far as it goes, but please let me know any points I could explain

Comment: @user7280899: a key difference between constructive and classical mathematics is that, in constructive mathematics, the representations of objects make a significant difference. So it is necessary to keep in mind at all times the precise kind of object that is being considered, and how it is represented in terms of concrete objects. In the question, there is no sense of the kind of object that $a$ and $b$ are. But (1) is provable constructively when $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, and not provable constructively when $a$ and $b$ are reals.

Comment: @fleablood: I think my answer will address your question. It just falls out of the definitions of the order relations on the reals, because these have quantifiers in them which are more challenging to manipulate in constructive math than in classical math.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, I believe it will.  My issue is I don't really know what the basis of a constructivist view point of the reals is. Whether we are constructing the reals from the order or vice versa.  I guess vice versa.

Comment: @fleablood: it's more like the construction in a basic analysis textbook, using either Dedekind cuts of Cauchy sequences. First, there is an existing order on the rationals. Then a new set of "reals" is defined, with a suitable equivalence relation as "equality". Finally, the order relations on the rationals are extended to create new order relations on the reals. In the constructive setting, though, this extension is not as routine as in the classical setting, so we do not end up with trichotomy, and the relationship between $<$ and $\leq$ is more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question does not indicate what kind of objects $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be. I will comment here on the most commonly interesting case: when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. I will also comment on the case when $a$ and $b$ are natural or rational numbers.

There are many constructive systems, and they differ in many ways. One kind of constructive system treats real numbers as Cauchy sequences of rational numbers with a fixed modulus of convergence, e.g. a sequence $(a_n)$ is defined to be a real number if $|a_n - a_m| < 2^{-n}$ when $n < m$. Bishop's system of constructive analysis treats the reals this way, for example.

In this setting, $(a_n) < (b_n)$ is defined to mean that, for some $m$, $a_m + 2^{-m} < b_m - 2^{-m}$. (See my note below.) This is classically equivalent to $\lim a_n < \lim b_n$, of course, as an easy exercise.

However $(a_n) \leq (b_n)$ is defined to mean that for all $n$, $a_n  \leq b_n + 2^{-n}$. (Again, see my note.) This is equivalent to the classical definition of $\lim a_n < \lim b_n$. The key point, though, is that $(a_n) < (b_n)$ is defined as an existential statement and $(a_n)\leq (b_n)$ is defined as a different universal statement.  Neither of these statements is defined as the negation of the other one, because that would not be a useful way to define them in constructive mathematics.

In these systems, $(a_n) \leq (b_n)$ is also *not* defined as $[(a_n) = (b_n)] \lor [(a_n) < (b_n)]$.  Neither of the order relations $<$, $\leq$ on the reals is defined in terms of the other.

Finally, $(a_n) = (b_n)$ is defined as $[(a_n) \leq (b_n)] \land [(b_n) \leq (a_n)]$.

These definitions are very different for reals than for naturals or rationals. For the latter two systems, we do have the full trichotomy principle, informally because if we have two naturals or rationals we can just look at them to see which is bigger or whether they are equal. This breaks down for the reals because of their representation as sequences of rationals.

With these definitions of the order on the reals, we do have that $(a_n) < (b_n) \to \lnot [(b_n) \leq (a_n)]$. To see this, assume we have an $m$ such that $a_m + 2^m < b_m - 2^m$. Then, if we also assume $b_m < a_m + 2^m$, we can obtain a contradiction $a_m < a_m$. Obtaining a contradiction is how we prove the negation of a statement in constructive systems.

On the other hand, we will not be able to prove $\lnot (b \leq a) \to (a < b)$ constructively. This is more difficult to show because we have to produce a counterexample. In this case, the underlying issue is [Markov's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_principle). Wikipedia lists an equivalent form of Markov's principle as:

> For each real number $x$, if it is contradictory that $x$ is equal to $0$, then there exists $y ∈ Q$ such that $0 < y < |x|$, often expressed by saying that x is apart from, or constructively unequal to, $0$.

In this case, if we know $\lnot (x = 0)$ then we can show constructively $\lnot (|x| \leq 0)$. However, without Markov's principle we cannot prove that $\lnot (x = 0) \to (\exists y)[0 < y < |x|]$, so we cannot prove $\lnot (a \leq 0) \to 0 < a$. Markov's principle is not usually included in constructive systems, although it has been thoroughly studied in that context.

The difficulty with Markov's principle is that it is true in the standard, classical natural numbers, so counterexamples that show it is not provable constructively have to use nonstandard models in some way, which makes these counterexamples difficult.

(Note: I am writing this from the top of my head, and so it may be necessary to replace $2^{-n}$ with $2^{-n-1}$ everywhere above, or similar small changes, depending on the source you'd like to follow. There can be some subtleties. But the key point is still that $a < b$ is a "positive" statement and $a \leq b$ is a "negative" statement, and the difference between them is tied to Markov's principle.)

Comment: Very well done!  Thanks for taking the time to write this, Carl!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. @amWhy

Comment: The OP has not mentioned anything at all about reals.

Comment: @Derek Elkins: I suppose that is true, but the reals are the most interesting case, and the answer will depend vitally on the type of object that is being considered.

Comment: That definition of real numbers seems to put the burden of constructivity on the ability to construct arbitrary sequences of rational numbers.  Is that not simply begging the question of constructibility?

Comment: Many sequences of rationals can be defined constructively, e.g. constant sequences, sequences converging to roots of polynomials, sequences converging to $\pi$ and $e$, etc.   The definition of real numbers is agnostic towards how the sequences of rationals are constructed, and I didn't focus on that issue here, but the idea is that once someone has a feeling about which sequences of rationals they have, that also determines their real numbers. Of course the same kind of construction, or via Dedekind cuts, is used in classical textbooks as well, and the same issue arises there. @DanielV

Answer (score 1):

If $a < b$ then $\neg(b \leq a)$ since if $b < a$ or $b = a$ then we have $a < a$ (Contradiction), so this implication actually holds.

If $a\leq b$ then $\neg(b<a)$, since if $b<a$ then $a < b$ and $a = b$ both imply $a<a$ (Contradiction).

---

To be more precise, here is a Natural deduction proof of the first implication:

```
a < b (As.)
| b <= a, i.e.: b < a v a = b (As.)
| | b < a (As.)
| | | a < a (Transitivity of <)
| | b < a implies a < a (Implication Introduction)
| | a = b
| | | a < a (property of =)
| | a = b implies a < a (Implication Introduction)
| | a < a (v Elimination)
| | Contradiction (Irreflexivity of <)
| not(b <= a) (Implication Introduction)
a < b implies (not( b <= a )) (Implication Introduction)
```

Constructing a counterexample for the reverse implications is not so easy. Here I'm assuming the existence of a so called "smooth topos", where you can do smooth infinitesimal analysis.

Given some preparations, define $\Delta := \{x : x^2  = 0\}$. The you can prove: for all $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ we have $\neg 0< \varepsilon$ and (!) $\neg0> \varepsilon$ even though there is an $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ with $\varepsilon \neq 0$. In this case $\neg 0 < \varepsilon$ even though $0\geq \varepsilon$ is false (this proves that the reverse implication in 2. is unprovable). Also since $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $\neg \varepsilon > 0$ we have $\neg \varepsilon \leq 0$ even though $\varepsilon > 0$ is false (this proves that the reverse implication in 1. is unprovable). For more detailed information see "A primer of smooth infinitesimal analyis" by Bell.

For a more "down to earth" approach you can try modifying the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115606/inequality-and-intuitionistic-logic), I guess.

Comment: @StefanPerko: I'm very skeptical with regard to "b <= a, i.e.: b < a v a = b" (the second line in your natural deduction). The latter would seem to be stronger than the former, as it implies that you can *decide* between b < a and a = b. Are you sure that they are equivalent in the constructive system you are using?

Comment: Well, I'll be damned if the confusion about my answer arises from this. I took this as the *definition* after reading the second comment beneath the question.

Comment: I mean if $b\leq a$ meant $\neg a < b$ then there would be nothing to prove (this is just $\neg \neg$-introduction)

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with the previous comments to your answer. I hadn't seen that @user7280899 suggested that definition, sorry. But I'm still skeptical about the suggestion, no matter who first made it. On page 18 of Bishop's _Foundations of Constructive Analysis_ a real number $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is defined to be positive if there is a natural number $n$ s.t. $x_n>n^{-1}$, while it is nonnegative if it is the case for all natural numbers $n$ that $x_n\geq -n^{-1}$.

Comment: @Casper Perhaps, but the question was about *strictly* partially ordered sets in general, as far as I can tell. In any case, my answer dealt with a *strict* poset.

Comment: @Stefan ....the question says nothing about a strictly partially ordered set.  It is a question about constructive mathematics.  The OP, in comments below their question, makes it pretty clear that they don't know about total order, or poset, or strict poset, or even an ordered set, etc.  Just please address comments without putting words in the OPs mouth.

Comment: The part above the line is correct, constructively, but the natural deduction proof assumes some things about the constructive order relations on reals that aren't right. In particular $a \leq b$ is not an abbreviation for $a = b$ or $a < b$.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclamer: This is based on what I remember about counterexamples involving creative subjects in intuitionism and my memory is a bit rusty. I may have made a mistake.)

I'm pretty sure that (1) is not true in intuitionism. Here is why:

Let $P$ be a mathematical proposition which has not yet been proved or disproved. Let $a$ be the decimal number $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ where $a_i$ is 1 if $P$ has been proved or disproved at day number $i$ counting from today, while $a_i$ is $0$ if $P$ has still not been proved or disproved on that day. Let $b$ be $0$.

$b\geq a$ is absurd, as proving that would amount to proving that $P$ cannot be proved or disproved, which cannot be done in intuitionism (it's very different from an axiomatic system). Hence $\neg(b\geq a)$.

On the other hand, $a>b$ is not true (at present) because we cannot indicate a day in the future when $P$ will be proved.

Therefore, (1) is not true (at present).